# C# MD5CryptoServiceProvider caching TransformBlock

Tags: c#, caching, md5

I it possible to cache results from TransformBlock so they can then be re-used for further hashing without the need to re-calculate the same hash each time.  Given the following small sample.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        {
            MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] exe = File.ReadAllBytes(@"..\..\..\md5cache\bin\Debug\md5cache.exe");
            byte[] wrk = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\..\md5cache\bin\Debug"));
            byte[] cmd = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"test" + i.ToString() + ".bin");
            md5.TransformBlock(exe, 0, exe.Length, null, 0);
            md5.TransformBlock(wrk, 0, wrk.Length, null, 0);
            md5.TransformFinalBlock(cmd, 0, cmd.Length);
            byte[] hash = md5.Hash;
            string hexHash = BitConverter.ToString(hash);
            Console.WriteLine(hexHash.Replace("-", ""));
        }
    }
```

exe and wrk's data never changes throughout the lifetime of the app but I can't find anyway of caching this to avoid needlessly recalculating the data each pass.

I've seen the property `CanReuseTransform`, but I'm not sure how this is used and as it appears to only be a getter I guess it is used to see if you can stack `TransformBlock/TransformFinalBlock.`

So does anyone know if this is possible? I guess I could create a new clonable MD5CryptoServiceProvider class assuming all the bits I need are available.

Comment: Given the size of the blocks we're talking about, have you considered what level of benefit this would actually provide? I suspect it's considerably less over the lifetime of a busy app than the time it took you to ask the question :)

Comment: If you're not bound by an existing protocol, you can simply switch to `Hash(Hash(exe)+Hash(wrk)+Hash(cmd))` preferably with (truncated) SHA-256 instead of MD5. Your scheme also doesn't mark the boundaries between the three parts, allowing different triples match a hash.

Comment: @Jon, This is just a minimal sample case to give an idea of the flow, the real usage would have many more blocks and many more reads.  If it was a trivial as the sample code posted, I wouldn't have asked. ;)

Comment: @CodesInChaos, unfortuantly I'm bound to MD5 due to pre-existing tools outside of my control, there can be clashes but this is for file caching and the cached data has extra blobs for resolving conflicts, I'm not sure what you mean by marking boundries though.

Comment: (exe="A", wrk="BC") and (exe="AB", wrk="C") result in the same hash.

Comment: Ah yes, this is OK as the inputs are controlled (and is simulating the other app which treats the data as one big blob - read + read + read -> hash) But yes, marking the sections is a good idea.

Comment: Either way, it can't be done which is all I wanted to know, thanks guys. :)